# styled components, with gatsby-link anchor tag css coloring

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, gatsby

I am trying to style a `<Link/>` component from `gatsby-link` package using `styled-components` package Normally I just create a `const` give it a `Name` set it equal to `styled.a` for example and write my css. However when I create a `const` for `<Link/>` I get a `Duplicate declaration "Link"` error. How do I style a `<Link>` component with `styled-components`.

Here is my code Below

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import styled from "styled-components";

const Header = styled.div`
  margin: 3rem auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  background:red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  color: aqua;
`;

const Link = styled.a`
  color: aqua;
`;


export default () => (
  <Header>
        <Title>
          <Link to="/">
            Gatsby
          </Link>
        </Title>
  </Header>
);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```babel
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const StyledLink = styled(props => <Link {...props} />)`
  color: aqua;
`;

// ...

<StyledLink to="/">
  Gatsby
</StyledLink>
```

---

**Outdated version (`gatsby` v1, `styled-components` v3):**

```babel
import Link from 'gatsby-link';

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  color: aqua;
`;

// ...

<StyledLink to="/">
  Gatsby
</StyledLink>
```

Comment: Just a note, this only seems to work with components that use the `styled('div')\`\`` syntax. Not the shorthand `styled.div\`\`` syntax that projects like `react-emotion` allow you to use.

Comment: Sidenote: With `gatsby": "^2.0.98",` I had to `import { Link } from "gatsby";` and then use `styled(props => <Link {...props} />)`, see https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1449#issuecomment-420087359

Answer (score 5):

Rename the `Link` import.

`import { Link as GatsbyLink } from "gatsby";`

If you name your component `Link` you might encounter naming collisions because that name is so ubiquitous among different frameworks. The error you describe points out that you have more than one component with the same name.

Name your components explicitly (adapted from @Fabian Schultz's answer):

```
import { Link as GatsbyLink } from "gatsby";

const StyledLink = styled(GatsbyLink)`
  color: aqua;
`;

// ...

<StyledLink to="/">
  Gatsby
</StyledLink>
```